# Cumulative custom function over grouped data in Python

Tags: python, r, function, pandas, plyr

I am looking to create a retention function over a pandas DataFrame which runs the cumulative function over grouped portions of the data.

I want to do something similar to what the R  *plyr* package does

Say I have some dummy data as of so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.repeat(np.arange(1,11), 5), 
               'y': np.tile(np.arange(1,6), 10)} )
```

This gives us (just showing 10 first lines):

```
   x  y
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  1  5
5  2  1
6  2  2
7  2  3
8  2  4
9  2  5
```

In this case 'x' is the column I want to group by and 'y' is what I want to run the function over.

The function is a retention function that applies some factor to the previous sum and adds that to the current value. In code form this is what  the function should look like (might be a better way):

```
def retention(x, r):
    n = len(x)
    D = np.zeros(n)
    D[0] = x[0]

    for i in range(1,n):
        D[i] = r*D[i - 1] +x[i]

    return D
```

However I want to function to essentially *start over* at the beginning of a new 'x' value.

The result should look like this:

```
   x  y
0  1  1
1  1  2.25
2  1  3.5625
3  1  4.890625
4  1  6.22265625
5  2  1
6  2  2.25
7  2  3.5625
8  2  4.890625
9  2  6.22265625
```

I need the solution to be flexible enough so that I could group by any number of columns and have variable lengths for the groups.

I've tried several methods but can not get the solution.

For example, this does **not** work:

```
grouped = df.groupby('x')
grouped.apply(lambda x: retention(df['y'],.25))
```

**NOTE: I have done this in R before using the *plyr* package:**

```
retention = function(x , r) {
  n =length(x)
  D = rep(0, n)
  D[1] = x[1]
  for (i in 2:n) {

    D[i]=r*D[i-1] + x[i]

  }
  return(D)
}

x = rep(1:10, each = 5)
y = rep(1:5, 10)
df = data.frame(x,y)

ddply(df, .(x),  summarize, y = retention (y, .25))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. 
It appears that your decay factor, if call it so, is 0.25, the following two steps do what is intended (first 10 observations printed, the resultant is called `z`):

```
In [67]:

z = df.groupby('x').y.apply(lambda x: np.convolve(x, np.power(0.25, range(len(x)))[:len(x)], mode='full')[:len(x)])
print z
x
1     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
2     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
3     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
4     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
5     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
6     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
7     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
8     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
9     [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
10    [1.0, 2.25, 3.5625, 4.890625, 6.22265625]
Name: y, dtype: object
In [68]:

print pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'x': i, 'z': v}) for i, v in zip(z.index.values, z.values)]).head(10)
   x         z
0  1  1.000000
1  1  2.250000
2  1  3.562500
3  1  4.890625
4  1  6.222656
0  2  1.000000
1  2  2.250000
2  2  3.562500
3  2  4.890625
4  2  6.222656
```

Basically, the cumulative sum operation (with a factor) is done using `numpy.convolve`. The rest is straight forward: just `groupby` the data into groups, apply the `convolve` and then `concat` the resultants together.

Comment: Thanks, CT! Been stuck on this for a while. Would not have though to do it this way.. very clever approach